# Creating Bode Plot from Experimental Data

Tags: phase, transfer-function, frequency-response, bode

I have a blackbox system in which I can input a function and obtain the output signal (in MATLAB). I'm attempting to reconstruct a Bode diagram and have had success with the Magnitude plot, however, I'm having a lot of difficulty with the phase plot. What I've tried to do is collect input and output data for the input $\sin(ft)$ where $f$ is the frequency that I am changing. For each frequency I am determining the phase shift by finding the time difference (I'll denote by $td$) between the input and output signal on a plot and calculating the phase shift using
$$td \div\frac{2\pi}{f}$$
After collecting the data over a range of frequencies I plot this (phase shift on y-axis, frequency on a log scale on the x axis). The plot does not at all look like a phase plot, I don't really see much of a pattern, nor does the scale seem correct for the phase shifts. Below are some examples of data I have collected for different frequencies:

Frequency: $f=0.05$: https://ibb.co/swCGLw8

Frequency: $f=10$: https://ibb.co/jL8JhTv

Frequency: $f=1000$: https://ibb.co/rkZ8WLh

Note that a filter has been applied to try and reduce the noise

Any help would be great!

EDIT: Image of the phase plot: https://ibb.co/K2LcHqJ

Comment: 1 - Please post your "Bode plot".

2 - You can filter to improve the quality of the measurement, but you should use the "filtfilt" method to remove the phase shift caused by the filter.

3 - You probably need to unwrap the phase so that your plot looks more like a Bode plot.

Comment: You show the plots of the input and output signal but you didn’t plot your actual Bode plot, can you include that? To compute the phase, hard limit the input and output and then XOR the result (multiply the two square waves). Filter this and the result will be linearly proportional to the phase shift crossing 0 at 90 degrees. This will take advantage of the entire sig to give you an avg result. Be careful if you are filtering the input waveforms as the filter will introduce its own phase shift, so you need to use the exact same filter— best to just do this on the product output of the two

Comment: The phase detector approach I gave you is useful over a range of 0 to 180 degrees after which it repeats (aliases)

Comment: @Ben I edited my question to include the phase plot. Thanks for the suggestion, currently I'm only using a lowpass filter on the output. If I were to use filtfilt instead, would I again just use it on the output? Moreover, what do you mean by unwrap the phase? Thanks!

Comment: @DanBoschen Thanks for the suggestion! I edited my question to include the phase diagram. For XORing the signals, do I square the input and output signals, multiply them together and plot that against time? What exactly would I be looking for on the plot?

Comment: Hard limit the two signals to remove any amplitude change and then simply multiply the two waveforms together- the average of that result will be proportional to phase (simplest low pass filter), varying linearly from Vmax to Vmin as the phase goes from 0 to 180 degrees. Try it and should be clearer to you.

Comment: Your phase plot looks good— the approach I give will reduce the noise as it will use all your samples to determine the phase and the shift is within range of that (you can go beyond 180 but just know you are seeing -Vmax to +Vmax linearly from 180 to 360 degrees so it is ambiguous which you are seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an input signal $ u = A cos(2\pi ft) $ and you measure an output signal
$y = B cos(2\pi ft + \theta) $

The $\frac{B}{A}$ ratio is the gain and $\theta$ is the phase shift for frequency $f$.

You could simply demodulate $y$ by multiplying by $x = cos(2\pi ft) - jsin(2\pi ft)$

$$ z(t) = y*x = \frac{B}{2}(cos(4\pi ft) + cos(\theta) + j(sin(4\pi ft) + sin(\theta))$$

Now simply compute the  average of $z(t)$ over multiple cycles so that the $cos(4\pi ft)$ and $sin(4\pi ft)$ terms will average to 0.

Divide the magnitude of $z_{mean}$ by $A$ to get the gain and compute the angle of $z_{mean}$ to get the phase shift.

The advantage of this method is that by averaging over multiple cycles, you will significantly reduce the noise and improve the accuracy of your phase and gain estimates. Apply this technique for multiple frequencies, you will get your Bode plot.

Comment: I really like this approach! Just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, I should calculate $x$ along the same time domain that I use for $y$, and then point-wise multiply $x$ and $y$ together.  I should do this many times and take the mean of all the $z$'s. Once I've done this, I will be left with $z_{mean}$ which is still a vector. How do I go from here to obtaining the angle? Do I take the average of the $z_{mean}$ vector, then compute the argument?

Comment: $z_{mean}$ is a complex number, so the angle of the complex number will be the phase shift.

Comment: What I'm confused about is the input signal and output signal will be a vector covering some time domain (ie. 0 to 10 seconds). So wouldn't $z$ also be a vector?

Comment: Yep, but the mean of z(t) over 10 seconds, $z_{mean}$ will be a complex number.

Comment: Ah I see my misunderstanding, thank you! Approximately how many cycles do you think would be appropriate? A concern I have is that when I'm dealing with really small frequencies, such as $0.0001$, the period is very large. Running the system for even a couple cycles at that frequency can take a very long time.

Comment: 0.0001 Hz is basically DC, so compute the average with the maximum number of points you can realistically manage.

Comment: I'm still in the process of collecting data for the high frequencies, but so far it's looking really good! I'm trying to fully understand the mathematics behind this technique. Would you be able to point me in the direction of some resources for this? There are a few things that aren't clear to me, for instance, why $y*x$ is what it is, why $\cos(4\pi ft)$ and $\sin(4\pi ft)$ average to zero. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: the average of a sine wave $ x = sin(2\pi ft) $ over a period of T is equal to 0. Therefore a sine wave $x = sin(4\pi ft) $ , twice the frequency will also be equal to 0.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Is there a name for this method or any resources? I'm trying to piece together the mathematics here so I can fully understand the method.

Comment: synchronous demodulation

Comment: One last question (I hope). For $z(t) = y*x$, is this a convolution or multiplication (I understand that in the frequency domain convolution results in multiplication, but I just want to check the meaning here)? Also, in that expression, how $A$ come in? It is not in $y$ nor $x$.

Comment: Multiplication

And A is the amplitude of your stimulus sine wave at frequency $f$

Comment: Am I right in that $z_{mean} = \frac{AB}{2}e^{i\theta}$? If so, how does $\frac{|z_{mean}|}{A}$ result in the gain, $\frac{B}{A}$?

Comment: what's the average of a sine wave over an integer number of cycles? Answer : 0

Comment: That would be the same for cosine as well, correct?  In which case $x(t)$ averages to zero... Now I'm confused since obviously $z \neq 0$. If $x(t)$ were to average out to $1$ this would all make sense... I think I'm nearly getting it

Comment: remember $\theta$ is a constant for a given frequency $f$. So $cos(\theta)$ is a constant. The average of $cos(4\omega t)$ will be 0.

The goal of averaging is to remove the $cos(4\omega t)$ and $sin(4\omega t)$ components.

Comment: That makes sense for the phase shift. It's the gain that I'm confused about. I believe my confusion lies in not understanding how $A$ comes into the expression $y*x$. We have that $y = B\cos(2\pi ft + \theta)$ and $x = \cos(2\pi ft) - i\sin(2\pi ft)$. In neither of those expressions is there an $A$, so I'm not sure how we get the $\frac{AB}{2}$ term for $z$.

Comment: You're the one generating the stimulus with amplitude $A$ and frequency $f$...

For example if A = 1 volt, and you measure B = 0.5V, the gain is 0.5 or -6 dB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121227/discussion-between-ben-and-migeve3630).